# Do US REU programs sponsor the student visas (J1 or F1) for international candidates?

Tags: united-states, undergraduate, research-undergraduate, international-students

US [REU programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Experiences_for_Undergraduates) sometimes accept "self-funded" international students. However, **do they also sponsor the student visa (J1 or F1) for the selected international candidates?** Or do the students have to use a tourist visa? (From what I read so far, using a tourist visa for that purpose would not be legal as REU programs fall in the "internship" or "training" category.)

**Edit**:

I noticed that the J1 requires that 51% of funding come from either the hosting institute or some external source. So I suppose the J1 wouldn't be applicable for international students. However, as far as I understand, the F1 is only applicable for students enrolled in a degree course in the US. **So is there no visa that would be applicable for international students willing to participate in a US REU program?** That seems contradictory as many REU programs clearly mention that they are open to international applicants. [[Source](https://internationaloffice.berkeley.edu/students/new/fj_compared)]

Comment: Do you have any example programs that are open to international applicants?

Comment: @Richard [Yes](http://london.ucdavis.edu/~zieve/REU/reu.html).

Comment: It looks like the best answer is to contact the specific program(s) your are applying to. The answer is specific to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends. Some will support your visa application others will accept international students only if they already hold a visa (sometimes a specific type of visa).

Answer (score 0):

All official participants in NSF REU programs must be US citizens or permanent residents per the [NSF REU homepage](https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/):

> Undergraduate students supported with NSF funds must be citizens or permanent residents of the United States or its possessions.

A self-funded student or non-NSF REU funded student would simply be an intern or student at the host institution.